# C++ When should a function/ call be static/ non-static?

Tags: c++, static, function-declaration

I have a function defined in a C++ source file called `spiral.cpp`, I am trying to call that function from another C++ source file called `manager.cpp`. However, I am getting a compile error that says "illegal call of non-static member function".

I have had a look for the reasons for getting this compile error, and everything I've found so far seems to tell me that I need to make the function `static` in its definition. However, if I do that, I then get a compile error that says that "'static' should not be used on member functions defined at file scope".

The function is defined in `spiral.cpp` with the code:

```
int spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber(void){
    ...
}
```

It is then called in `manager.cpp` with the line:

```
spiral::updateCircuitNumber();
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? Is the problem definitely to do with the function being defined/ called as static/ non- static incorrectly, or is it something else?

Comment: Are you sure that you want a static function? At least the name implies that you are manipulating state (of a `spiral` instance(?))

Comment: No- I'm not sure that I want a static function... that's why I'm asking the question... The compiler is telling me that something needs to be static- whether it's the function definition/ call/ both- I'm not sure. I don't really understand what static is/ does...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, your function name makes me assume that you actually want to manipulate state of a particular `spiral` instance. In this case, you would need (or at least usually use) a *member* function. It seems this is what you actually did. Check.
Now, in order to *call* this function, you need to have an instance of `spiral` that you can call the function on.

```
spiral s;
s.updateCircuitNumber();
```

or (if allocated dynamically)

```
spiral * s = new spiral();  // better use appropriate smart_ptr but that's another story
s->updateCircuitNumber();
```

These calls change the state of that particular `s`object. If you have another `spiral`object `s2`, this remains unchanged and you are free to call `updateCircuitNumber()`for that instance as well as needed. **Non-static member functions** are also called **instance functions** because they operate on a particluar instance of a class.

**`static`** functions are also referred to as **class functions** because they are independent of a particular instance of that class. Therefore, they may only access static members of that class, but not non-static ones (as these only exist for a particular instance which is not available). As mentioned in the other answers, the `static` keyword is only added inside the class declaration. Static function can then be called as you tried with `spiral::updateCircuitNumber();`.

Comment: That is correct- I do want to manipulate the state of a particular spiral instance. I tried doing this by creating an instance of `spiral` and calling the function on that instance with: `spiralItem newSpiral = new spiralItem();` and `newSpiral::updateCircuitNumber();`, but this gave me three errors: 1. "'initializing': cannot convert from 'spiralItem *' to 'spiralItem'"... I can't see where I'm using the pointer it mentions here... 2. "'newSpiral' : left of '::' must be class/ struct/ union", 3. "'updateCircuitNumber' : identifier not found"...

Comment: If you allocate dynamically, you get a *pointer* so you need to declare `spiralitem * newSpiral...`(see my answer). To call the function on that instance, you need to use the `->` operator (or `.` for objects on the stack) *on that instance*: `newSpiral->updateCircuitNumber();` as noted in my answer above.

Comment: Brilliant, that has got it working- thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `static` inside the class declaration but **not** in the function definition:

```
class spiralItem
{
...
public:
    static int updateCircuitNumber(void);
};
```

and in `spiral.cpp`:

```
int spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber(void){
    ...
}
```

You call the function in `manager.cpp` by writing:

`spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber();`

Simply regard this as the rule for C++; it does appear a little odd at first.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer- I've given that a go- so I now have the function defined in `spiralItem.cpp` with: `int spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber(void){...}`, and am calling it in `manager.cpp` with `static spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber();`, but I now get a compile error on the line in `manager.cpp` that says, "member function redeclaration not allowed"... Any idea why this is?

Comment: Drop the `static` from the function call and use the class name `spiralItem` (there's no need to use an instance of the class, although you can).

Comment: I have done that, but I get an error that says "member function redeclaration not allowed". Currently, the function is declared in `spiralItem.cpp` with: `int spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber(void){...}`, and called in `manager.cpp` with `int spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber();`. I can't see how this is redeclaring the function...?

Comment: `int spiralItem::updateCircuitNumber();` is not *calling* a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can have static member functions in a class. First thing to note here is that static member functions don't have this pointer that means you cannot access any data member/non-static member functions of class in static function as they requires this pointer.Second point is that static member function can be called without instantiating a class.

For e.g:-

```
class One
{
private:
   static int count;
public:
  static int getCount ()
  {
    return count;
  }
};
```

You have to initialize count in .cpp file:-

```
int One::count = 0;
```

And then you can call member function like this:-

```
std::cout << One::getCount () << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is probably in the header file. How do you declare your static method?

Here is how it should look like considering your example:

```
class spiralItem {
public:
  static int updateCircuitNumber(void);
};
```

Comment: I have declared the function in the header file with: `int updateCircuitNumber(void);`. Should I now be making this declaration static?

Comment: You should declare it just as my example shows. The static keyword only goes in the header file.The static keyword also only goes into a class declaration, and not for global functions.